# How I can get distinct records from laravel table using elequent model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have to fetch distinct records based on the entity ID . I have tried this but it is not working

```
User::where('id',$id)->with(['userRoleEntity' => function($q) { $q->distinct('entityId'); }])->first();
```

I should get two records in the user entity array but I am getting 3. How I can fix this ? thanks in advance

the value in the square should not be there https://prnt.sc/qkamdi

Comment: because that user have 3 role assign may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[distinct](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_distinct) method not support to pass an parameter, you need to select a field and `distinct`

```php
User::where('id',$id)->
    with(['userRoleEntity' => function($q) { 
      $q->select('entityId')->distinct(); 
}])->first();
```

or

Try this one:

```php
User::where('id',$id)->
    with(['userRoleEntity' => function($q) { 
      $q->groupBy('entityId'); 
}])->first();
```